# Mac OS X options for running a Ruby file in the background repeatedly

Tags: ruby, macos, geektool

I wrote a Ruby script that I want to run in the background repeatedly as long as the computer is running.  I was planning on using [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) to get this .rb file to run in the background, but I'm having issues [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883664/ruby-mac-geektool-question-file-access-rights) using GeekTool to run my script.

The thing is that I want this script to be a complete surprise (it's a message display system for my wife) so I want to be able to have it start running every time her computer starts up and keep running as long as her computer is on.  If I can't use GeekTool to do it then I have no idea what to use.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geektool ended up working out for my needs after all.

Answer (score 4):

You use [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Lingon](http://lingon.sourceforge.net/) (despite not being actively supported) will help you create a launchd setup, and has quick access to the launchd man pages.